# How to add dot in htaccess rewrite rule regex?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create my url structure like dir view (example.com/dir1/dir2/file) For which I am using htaccess mod rewrite as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@/]+)/?$ get.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The code above works fine except that if I try to add dot like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@/.]+)/?$ get.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The .htaccess breaks. "Internal Server Error"

Comment: You need escape it `\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you add a dot in the pattern then your pattern also matches the target url **get.php**  and rewrites **get.php** to **get.php** on second rewrite cycle. This results in an infinite loop/Rewrite loop error.

You need a RewriteCond to prevent this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/get.php
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@/.]+)/?$ get.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need escape the dot `\.` , i.e.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@/\.]+)/?$ get.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: No need to escape the dot. there is something else going on